# Laravel + Ajax function - update view on 'activated' state

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I just started working with ajax, and i am kinda stuck now. I have a ajax function that 'GET' all the values i need to be shown in my view and formats it as html.
The way i do it now to update the news that are shown in the view, is i call on the script in my view and let it have a interval (1000ms).

Now I am trying to figure out how to only run ajaxGetAllActiveNews() when a news post is activated (when a post is toggled from 0 -> 1) by my controller. And if no posts are activated i want a default 'news' to be shown.

I am open to all solutions! Thanks!

The view:

```
 <!-- News Activator -->
    <script>
        setInterval(function () {
            ajaxGetAllActiveNews();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Ajax function:

```
function ajaxGetAllActiveNews() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/infoskjerm',
        method: 'GET'
    }).error(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }).done(function (news) {
        console.log(news);

        var titleToAppendToView = [];

        $(news).each(function (key, value) {
            titleToAppendToView.push('<td>' + value.title + '</td>');

        });

        $('#title').html(titleToAppendToView);


        var authorToAppendToView = [];

        $(news).each(function (key, value) {
            authorToAppendToView.push('<td>' + value.author + '</td>');

        });

        $('#author').html(authorToAppendToView);


        var messageToAppendToView = [];

        $(news).each(function (key, value) {
            messageToAppendToView.push('<td>' + value.message + '</td>');

        });

        $('#message').html(messageToAppendToView)


        var picturePathToAppendToView = [];

        $(news).each(function (key, value) {


            if (typeof value.picture_path !== 'undefined' && value.picture_path.length > 0) {
                picturePathToAppendToView.push('<img src="../uploads/' + value.picture_path + '"> </img>');
            }

        });

        $('#picture').html(picturePathToAppendToView);

    });
}
```

My Controller for ajax and active news:

```
public function toggleActive($id)
{
    $news = News::findOrFail($id);
    $input = Input::except(['_token']);

        if($news->active == 0) {
            $news->active = 1;
            $news->update($input);
        }
        else {
            $news->active = 0;
            $news->update($input);
        }
    return Redirect::to('adminpanel/newsmodule');
}


 //Skriver ut alle active nyheter til infoskjerm view
public function ajaxGetAllActiveNews()
{
    $news = News::where('active', '=', '1')->get();
    return Response::json($news);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSocket (http://socketo.me/). This will allow you to push and pull via ZMQ (http://zeromq.org/bindings:php). And for client side handling you might need Autobahn (http://autobahn.ws/).

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, i rewrote my code to this. The code now gets all active news from the database and limits it to the 3 newest posts that where updated. Then my ajax function takes all posts and shows them in my view.

My controller:

```
public function ajaxGetAllActiveNews()
{
    $news = News::where('active', '=', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
    return Response::json($news);
}
```

And my Ajax:

```
function ajaxGetAllActiveNews() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/infoskjerm',
        method: 'GET'
    }).error(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }).done(function (news) {
        console.log(news);

        var titleToAppendToView = [];

        $(news).each(function (key, value) {

            if (typeof value.picture_path !== 'undefined' && value.picture_path.length > 0)
            {
                var imgpath = '<img id="news-picture" width="100%" src="/uploads/' + value.picture_path + '"></img>';
            }
            else
            {
                imgpath = '';
            }

            titleToAppendToView.push('<div><h2>' + value.title + '</h2><h3>Utgiver: ' + value.author + '</h3><h4> Publisert: '
                                    + value.created_at + '</h4><p>' + value.message + '</p>' + imgpath + '</div>');

            $('#news-content').html(titleToAppendToView).append();
        });
    });
}
```